# Git blame regex to extract commit, line number and code

Tags: regex, git

I'm trying to make a regex to format output of git blame into:

- SHA
- line number
- code

So that:

```
f02d38023450 (PersonA         2019-08-03 13:27:04 +0200 2338) <whitespace>
a7ebc6f94ab4 (PersonB         2019-11-04 12:05:07 +0100 2339) "<some code>"
a7ebc6f94ab4 (PersonA         2019-11-04 12:05:07 +0100 2340) <some code>       
f02d38023450 (PersonA         2019-08-03 13:27:04 +0200 2341) <whitespace>
```

becomes:

```
[
  {SHA: f02d38023450, line: 2338, code: <whitespace>}
  ...
]
```

Comment: `^(?<SHA>[0-9a-f]+)\s+\(\S+\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\ [+-]\d{4}\s+(?<line>\d+)\)\ ?(?<code>.*)$`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EMtdbj/1) - Or shorter: `^(?<SHA>[0-9a-f]+)\s+\(.+\s+(?<line>\d+)\)\ ?(?<code>.*)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const text = 
`
f02d38023450 (PersonA         2019-08-03 13:27:04 +0200 2338) <whitespace id="abc">
a7ebc6f94ab4 (PersonB         2019-11-04 12:05:07 +0100 2339) <some code>
a7ebc6f94ab4 (PersonA         2019-11-04 12:05:07 +0100 2340) <some "random" code>
f02d38023450 (PersonA         2019-08-03 13:27:04 +0200 2341) <whitespace>
`
let fields = text.replace(/"/gm, '\\"') // Escape double quotes
fields = fields.replace(/^(\w+) \(.+\+\d{4} (\d+)\) (.*)$/gm, '{ "SHA": "$1", "line": $2, "code": "$3" },') // Capture groups
fields = fields.slice(0, fields.length - 2) // Remove last comma
fields = `[${ fields }]` // Enclose in an array

let output = JSON.parse(fields)
console.log("output: ", output)
```

Note that double-quotes `"` have been escaped in case your code contains this character. The regex used is: `/^(\w+) \(.+\+\d{4} (\d+)\) (.*)$/gm` (full spec: https://regex101.com/r/jMMEfu/3). And it basically means:

- `^(\w+)`: Look for the start of the line and then any word.
- `\(.+\+\d{4} (\d+)\)`: Then a group of parenthesis which have a string like "+NNNN" (N is any decimal) followed by another decimal (the number lines).
- `(.*)$`: Then any word until the end of the string.

All groups are saved into capturing groups and used to compose the result string.

Comment: That works amazing i just have an issue when parsing, sometimes the code contains double quotes which fails the JSON parsing, is there any simple solution to that?

Comment: You need to escape characters. I've updated the snippet to do so @Arin